# What is the meaning of "Ganpati Bappa Morya"?

Tags: ganesha, festivals

I heard this many times but don't know what it means.

Is Ganpati another name for Ganesha?

What is bappa and Morya?

Answer (score 7):

Regard less of true story of Moraya Gosavi, that doesn't make anysense to say "Ganpati Bappa Moraya"... Actually splitting the word Moraya as "Mhora ya" means "come ahead and bless us" make sense here.

Thus *"Ganapati Bappa Moraya"* means *"Lord Ganesha Bless us"*
(Here Bappa is used for Lord...)

If in case you're interested in reading one of the famous prayers with english translation, follow the link. [Ganpati Aarti (with Translation)](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/ganapati-aarti-sukhkarta-dukhharta-with-english-translation-free-download-mp3)

Answer (score 3):

[Morya Gosavi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morya_Gosavi)  was a prominent saint and the greatest devotee of Lord Ganesha. Morya is associated with the name of lord Ganapati as veneration to this great devotee.

Comment: Thank you. At least you explained who is Morya but I still don't know the meaning of "Ganpati Bappa Morya!".

Comment: Morya Gosavi story has no substance and is a internet driven copy-paste phenomenon.

Answer (score 3):

Morya is changed verson of mor+ yaa
Which is again changed from  samor+yaa
Samor= in front of some one 
And yaa=come 
That means morya=samor yaa= be in front ( of us)
= guide us

Comment: you should cite sources!

Comment: downvoted due to lack of sources and impossible logic. why `Sa` would be deleted?

Answer (score 3):

It is considered as a chant but have some Marathi meaning you need to consider.

Morya Mean
1 Go ahead (for Visarjan ceremony happen.)
2 It is Marathi ward mohre ya mean pudhe Vha (for Visarjan ceremony happen.)
3 It look like lolhapuri Language word mhore ya(go ahead)
ref: Page on wordpress.com
[Quora Answer to Morya](https://www.quora.com/What-does-Morya-mean-when-they-say-Ganpati-bappa-Morya-during-Ganeshotsav)
[image]
[jodiif.wordpress.com](https://jodiif.wordpress.com/2010/09/14/%E2%80%9Cganpati-bappa-morya%E2%80%9D-%E2%80%93-what-it-means/)

[http://www.karmayog.org/](http://www.karmayog.org/articlesbyexperts/articlesbyexperts_9662.htm)

[yahoo QnA](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080903060310AAS971U)

[Another Yahoo QnA](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100917045109AAh7sm6)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, Ganapathi is another name of Lord Ganesha which means the Lord/Owner of all Shiva Gana (The army of Lord Shiva).
2. Bappa means Father/Lord and Morya refers to the greatest devotee of Lord Ganesha. To understand the meaning completely, "Ganapathi Bappa Morya" alone is not sufficient. The entire stanza "Ganapathi Bappa Morya, Purchya Varshi Laukar ya" is needed, which means "O Lord/Father Ganesha, come again next year fast".